# Does Dyndle require model service?

Tags: sites-9, dyndle

We are planning to use dyndle with SDL Tridion 9.1 for our new project. Does dyndle require model service? what are the advantage and disadvantage of dyndle over dxa.

Answer (score 3):

Well, from their official FAQ page, it requires [DD4T](https://www.dyndle.com/faq.html).
So you need to setup DD4T properly, and then build Dyndle on top of that. I might be mistaken, but Q will give you a definite answer.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, Marko. So no model service needed. Just plain Tridion and the DD4T template building blocks. Please check https://www.dyndle.com/docs/ for more information.

Comment: Regarding your second question: I don't know if this is the place for such a debate, but the short summary is:  DXA is a web application which you can use off-the-shelf, while Dyndle is a framework which you use in your own web application. The topic is also addressed concisely in the frequently asked questions section of the site: https://www.dyndle.com/faq.html